# Where can I find Sign of Ill Omen?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

Maddening Hex (Xanathar's Guide to Everything, p57) refers to Sign of Ill Omen:

> As a bonus action, you cause a psychic disturbance around the target cursed by your hex spell or by a warlock feature of yours, such as Hexblade's Curse or **Sign of Ill Omen**.

In that book I only found *Hound* of Ill Omen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a Warlock invocation from the PHB. You can find it on page 111.